# Python: Given the index of a substring, how to determine what the substring is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
str01 = "apple"
```

In Python, if I am given a specific string, and I want to determine the substring with index 3, how to achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by substring with index 3?

Comment: Substring starting with character at index 3?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you need, and what exactly your issue is in doing that? Using an index to access a string (or any other sequence) is extremely basic Python functionality that most tutorials should cover.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean exactly by `the substring with index 3`:

Substring starting with the character at index 3

```
>>> str01[3:]
'le'
```

Substring ending with the character at index 3 (inclusive):

```
>>> str01[:4]                                                                                                                          
'appl'
```

Comment: The first one! Thanks! The problem troubles me a lot, and now it's solved.